Math_Physics - Why $\Sigma$ in $\frac{d}{dt}q(t) + \oint_S j\cdot dS = \Sigma$?
I'm working on understanding continuity equations, which look like:
$$\frac{d}{dt}q(t) + \oint_S j\cdot dS = \Sigma.$$
The first two terms are time variance of a quantity and the associated flux of a current through a closed surface.
In a previous post, I was able to explain the opposing relationship between the first two terms along with why we must choose the outward orientation, etc. Now it boils down to what this extra term is explicitly? Since we have the relation to divergence already:
$$\int_{\partial V}j\cdot dS = \int_Vdiv(j)dV,$$
I am skeptical that $\Sigma$ is necessary to quantify sources/sinks of the $q(t)$ entity, unless it is coming from a separate mechanism/current -- in which case, why are we not allowed to combine such currents?

In the wiki post linked above, there are 2 examples for which $\Sigma \neq 0$: the Human/Building example and the Semiconductor example.
The first example treats the number of humans in a building as $q(t)$, with the flux given by people entering and exiting the building. The $\Sigma$ term is positive if someone gives birth and negative if someone dies in the building. Under normal circumstances like a hospital, a person who is pregnant would enter the building as two (or more) people and the person that dies eventually gets taken out of the building, so we can attribute each of these to the current/field.
In the semiconductor example, it seems $G_n$ and $R_n$ (respectively generation and recombination of electrons) contribute to the $\Sigma$ term. But, superficially both the drift and diffusion currents are of charge carriers in the semiconductor itself, so together with these $G_n$ and $R_n$ events, the whole process should be described by one current of charge carriers.
Is it just convenient to separate the two terms or is it necessary?

If you set $\sum=0 =\sum S_{-ource}+\sum S_{-inks}$, if there is only one source or only one then, the equality is not verified. your problem is directly linked to the Stokes theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem and by far to the Cauchy integral https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_theorem

@ I Zuka| : Yes, see :https://mathoverflow.net/questions/83965/interesting-applications-of-the-classical-stokes-theorem                https://archive.org/details/smirnov-a-course-of-higher-mathematics-vol-2-advanced-calculus/Smirnov%20-%20A%20Course%20of%20Higher%20Mathematics%20-%20Vol%202%20-%20Advanced%20Calculus/page/227/mode/1up?view=theater

page 231 :
If certain points of the domain are sources, we can exclude these points and get a domain with holes in which (45) is valid. The cyclical constant for a hole is equal to integral (44) over a contour encircling the hole, and evidently gives the quantity of fluid g produced by the corresponding source in unit time. The function y(M) is now many-valued. If q < 0, the source is negative (a sink).

So based on application, I think it is safe to say there aren't any holes in our space. So perhaps homology isn't the right place to look. Nor is any complex analysis. Really it should be 3D reals with time, but I thought the generalization to $\mathbb{R}^n$ or real manifolds was okay. Maybe I'll update to include simply connected.

@I Zuka I ,Yes, If we take a volume delimited by a surface S (simply conex), we know how to calculate the flow (of liquid, heat, etc.) through this surface and we obtain the continuity equation, see page 327, In physics, sources and sinks are added without mentioning the implicit mathematical tools which must be implemented...

See Nate Eldredge's answer:https://mathoverflow.net/questions/57025/down-to-earth-uses-of-de-rham-cohomology-to-convince-a-wide-audience-of-its-usefu

You keep referencing page numbers without a text? And Nate's answer seems of marginal relevance with a geometrically open surface (ours is closed) and a discussion of curl of vector field (whereas ours is divergence) and existence of a potential function (ours goes from $\omega$ to $d\omega$, i.e. the other way)?

The best elucidation I have found is in the article on Continuum Mechanics. There the problem's concept gets complicated in a few ways: the control volume is allowed to deform, it is allowed to move relative to the flow field, and sources are considered not only inside the volume, but on the boundary as well.


In the section called Balance Laws, we find:
$$\color{maroon}{\frac{d}{dt}\bigg[\int_{\Omega}f(\boldsymbol{x},t)dV\bigg] := \int_{\partial \Omega}f(\boldsymbol{x},t)[u_n(\boldsymbol{x},t)-\boldsymbol{v}(\boldsymbol{x},t)\cdot \boldsymbol{n}(x,t)]dA+\int_{\partial \Omega}g(\boldsymbol{x},t)dA+\int_{\Omega}h(\boldsymbol{x},t)dV}$$
where $f(x,t),g(x,t),\text{ and }h(x,t)$ are functions describing respectively: the "physical quantity" flowing through the body and sources thereof on the surface and interior.

Their choice of symbols in my opinion could be better, but not to be confused with the pathline, the speed at which the bounding surface moves is $u_n$. Notice if we have:
$$u_n := 0$$
$$\color{red}{\Sigma(t)} := \int_{\partial \Omega}g(x,t)dA + \int_{\Omega}h(x,t)dV$$
the equation can be rewritten as:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\bigg[\int_{\Omega}fdV\bigg]+\int_{\partial\Omega}fv\cdot dS = \Sigma(t)$$
From which it is not a stretch to relate with the problem statement.

This more-so explicit form for $\Sigma(t)$ has the advantage of phrasing sources so that they look like the density function, $f$ (or $\rho$ as it relates to $q$, in the other post, $u(x,t)$). But as well, it makes the equation more computer ready, say if you wanted to test out different instances of $g$ and $h$ in a simulation.
It remains to theoretically tie $\Sigma$ back together with the flow field $j = fv$ ($X$ in the "previous post") and with other things that claim to be continuity equations like the Reynolds Transport Theorem seen in Frank White's "Fluid Mechanics (5ed)" (p.136) or Fox and McDonald's "Introduction to Fluid Mechanics (3ed)" (p.103).
Neglecting the latter, note that algebraically we can combine the integrals that have the same domain and differential form and make use of the Divergence Theorem to translate the flux term to the desired domain. Say for example that $g(x,t)\equiv 0$ and we apply the theorem, then we can combine the RHS of the Balance Equation:
$$= \int_{\Omega}[h-div(fv)]dV$$
If we interpret $h(x,t)$ as the divergence of some auxiliary field, by linearity of the divergence operator, the integrand is actually the divergence of the combined field as conjectured. So long story short, I would use the Balance Equation as the primary tool to be interpreted.


This equation seems to have been built philosophically, it needs to be experimentally verified (I'm sure it has been done). The Liebniz-Reynolds Theorem is mathematically based so is in a sense self-verified. So it is worth comparing the two.
